# Forced footer to the bottom of the page

Tags: php, css, footer

I have tried a number of ways getting my footer absolutely down, but to no avail. I'm looking for a way of getting images, hyperlinks and text into a footer (since I can't post images due to being a new on stackoverflow here's the link to image of what I need within the footer - http://liep2vsk.edu.lv/footer.png). The site's web pages are of various vertical lengths, but I need the footer to stay down at all times without scrolling.

I want to outsource the footer into a separate footer.php file and link it via include function into a web page.

I've tried using the wrapper for the footer, but it doesn't seem to work - http://liep2vsk.edu.lv/footer.php. Did I mention I need it centered?

p.s. I'm new here and I know my site's code isn't clean since there are a lot of AP Divs. Trying to learn some CSS basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body style="position:absolute;height:100%">
  <div id="container" style="min-height:90%"></div>
  <div id="footer" style="position:fixed;margin-bottom:0px">
     <div id="apDiv1"><img src="ico/mail_1.png" width="256" height="256"></div>
     <div id="apDiv2">Some text</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This one actually worked.Thanks. However these still are scrollable . Here's footer.css - http://liep2vsk.edu.lv/footer.php and the page I'm trying to view it on -http://liep2vsk.edu.lv/Publiskie_iepirkumi.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ubb3psmp/

```
<style>
.fixedFooter{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
}
</style>

<div class="fixedFooter">
Something in footer!
</div>
```